# data.map is not a funcion react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, redux, components

Hello everyone my problem is the following, I am using redux and react for some reason when I move to another view and go back to the previous one I get this error data.map is not a function this is my main component
I tried to solve it by validating if I had something inside the array with the "?" but it still didn't work, and I added a validation in my main path but it still didn't work either.

```
const HomeScreen = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    responsiveMobile();
  });

  return (
<>
  <Banner id="BannerHome">
    <img src="/assets/images/Banner.png" alt="" />
  </Banner>

  <ListAdopt>
    <SubTitle className="space m-0" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
      ¿Quieres Adoptar?
    </SubTitle>
    <div className="content-swiper">
      <ContainerTwo>
        <SwiperAdopt />
        <ButtonTarjet>
          <Link to="/">
            VER TODOS
          </Link>
        </ButtonTarjet>
      </ContainerTwo>
    </div>
  </ListAdopt>

  <ListNotAdopt className="adopt">
    <SubTitle className="space m-0" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
      Animales adoptados recientemente
    </SubTitle>
    <AdoptAnimal>
      <ContainerTwo>
        <SwiperNotAdopt />
        <ButtonTarjet>
          <Link to="/">
            VER TODOS
          </Link>
        </ButtonTarjet>
      </ContainerTwo>
    </AdoptAnimal>
  </ListNotAdopt>

  <ListAdopt className="p-0">
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="row">
        <LeftContent className="col-6">
          <ContainerLeft>
            <Campanias />
          </ContainerLeft>
        </LeftContent>
        <BackgroundCampania className="col-6">
          <img src="/assets/images/bannerDos.png" alt="banner" />
        </BackgroundCampania>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ListAdopt>
  <ModalLogin />
</>
```

);
};

This is the validation

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadAnimals());
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user?.uid) {
        dispatch(login(user.uid, user.displayName, user.email));
        setLog(true);
      }
    }); 
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoad(true);
    }, 1500);
  }, [dispatch]);  

    if (!load) {
    return <h1>Espere...</h1>;
  }
```

And this is the component that receives the error

```
const SwiperAdopt = () => {
  const { data } = useSelector((state) => state.load);

  return (
    <Swiper
      spaceBetween={0}
      autoplay={{
        delay: 3000,
      }}
      pagination={{ clickable: true }}
      breakpoints={{
        600:{
          slidesPerView: 1
        },
        650:{
          slidesPerView: 2
        },
        1000:{
          slidesPerView: 3
        }
      }}
    >
      {data?.map((animal) => {
        if (!animal.adopt) {
          return (
            <SwiperSlide key={animal.id} className="height-swiperTwo">
              <HeaderAdopt
                style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${animal.image})` }}
              ></HeaderAdopt>
              <BodyAdopt className="py-4">
                <ContainerBody>
                  <TitletBody className="pb-2">{animal.title}</TitletBody>
                  <Paragraph style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                    {animal.description}
                  </Paragraph>
                  <ButtonTarjet>
                    <Link to={`/details/${animal.id}`}>CONOCER MÁS</Link>
                  </ButtonTarjet>
                </ContainerBody>
              </BodyAdopt>
            </SwiperSlide>
          );
        }
        return false;
      })}
    </Swiper>
  );
};
```

Comment: seems data got updated to some object after navigation, make sure `data` in load reducer must be an array,

Answer (score 0):

Please try not to destruct data while using useSelector but use it like this:

`const data = useSelector((state) => state.load);`

Then instead of

```
data?.map((animal) =>
```

use

```
data?.data?.map((animal) =>
```